# Split graph into independent maximal cliques?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Does Mathematica have a method to partition the vertices of a graph into maximal independent subsets, such that each subset generates a complete subgraph?

**Edit:** The partition should be maximal in the sense that the inclusion of a new vertex into any subset should result in non-empty intersections between the subsets, or in the subsets no longer generating complete subgraphs.

Comment: igraph has [`maximal.clqiues`](http://igraph.org/r/doc/cliques.html) (is it what you need?), so you can use [IGraphR](http://www3.nd.edu/~szhorvat/pelican/using-igraph-from-mathematica.html).  Is this an acceptable solution?  (I think I recommended this package to you before.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Not exactly, because maximal cliques are not a partition of the vertices (some maximal cliques intersect each other). I want to partition the vertices into cliques.

Comment: What is the result you'd expect here? `Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 
  3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7, 
  6 <-> 7}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`.  `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7}}` and `{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7}}` are both good solutions?

Comment: I don't expect a specific result. I know there are several ways to do the partition I want. What I want is something similar to what FindGraphCommunitites does, but only choosing communities that are cliques. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I was just trying to make sure I understood.  It sounds like my example above is correct, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a graph on the maximal cliques, where cliques are joined if they share any elements. Then you find maximal independent sets in the derived graph-of-cliques. (This is easily adaptable if you do not require cliques to be maximal, just throw in a bunch more vertices into `cv` to account for sub-cliques.)

```
n = 15; a = RandomReal[{0.7, 0.9}];
g = RandomGraph[{20, Ceiling[a n (n - 1)/2]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
cv = Join[FindClique[g, n, All]];
ce = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[cv], i++,
 For[j = 1, j < i, j++,
  If[Intersection[cv[[i]], cv[[j]]] != {}, 
   ce = Append[ce, cv[[j]] <-> cv[[i]]]]
 ];
];
cg = Graph[cv, ce, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
FindIndependentVertexSet[cg]
```

This is not especially efficient, I'm not sure if you are looking to do some massive computation, in which case a more clever or efficient implementation is necessary. But this is quite easy and requires only the two basic commands `FindClique` and `FindIndependentVertexSet` (which are really the same anyway). Note that these commands always return maximal things (so `FindClique` will not return `{1,2,3}` if it also returns `{1,2,3,4}` in its list of cliques).

In this, I've just used `n` and `a` to give us a fairly dense graph.

The `FindClique[g,n,All]` means it finds `All` cliques in `g` up to size `n` (i.e. all sizes). Now, the last line may actually not be what you want. I guess what you really want is not maximal in terms of vertices of `cv`, but in terms of the total number of vertices covered by that independent-set-of-cliques in the original `g`, in which case, you can use a similar hack to get:

```
is = FindIndependentVertexSet[cg, Length[cv], All];
ism = 0; L[s_] := Length[Union[s]]; ismax = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[is], i++,
 Which[
  L[is[[i]]] > ism, ismax = {is[[i]]}; ism = L[is[[i]]],
  L[is[[i]]] == ism, ismax = Append[ismax, is[[i]]]
 ];
];
```

The entire set of maximum size maximal clique sets is `ismax` and you can see them all with `GraphHighlight` if you want. That might look something like:

```
BuildCliques[iss_] := Join[
 Union @@ iss,
 Union @@ 
 Table[Map[#[[1]] <-> #[[2]] &, Subsets[iss[[i]], {2}]], {i, 1, Length[iss]}]
];
Manipulate[
 Graph[g, GraphHighlight -> BuildCliques[is[[i]]]],
 {i, 1, Length[is], 1}]
```

I haven't really taken any time to make this code clever or optimized, but I think it does what you want, although probably not good for large graphs.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the [clique cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover) and it is [equivalent to colouring the complement graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover#Relation_to_coloring).

Thus we can use the colouring functionality from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

Here's an example:

This is just a style that makes it easier to see what is going on, and cross-reference the visualization with the raw result.

```
style = {GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack", VertexSize -> {"Scaled", 0.05}, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> White, EdgeStyle -> Thick};
```

Here's a sample graph:

```
SeedRandom[42]
rg = RandomGraph[{20, 40}, style]
```

[image]

Find the vertex cover:

```
cover = IGMembershipToPartitions[rg]@IGMinimumVertexColoring@GraphComplement[rg]
(* {{1, 3}, {2, 14, 16}, {4, 9}, {5, 13, 20}, {6, 10}, {7, 18}, {8, 11}, {12, 19}, {15, 17}} *)
```

`IGMembershipToPartitions` is just a helper to convert a list of colours into groups of vertices having the same colour. You can read up on it in detail in the IGraph/M documentation.

Visualize it:

```
HighlightGraph[rg, Subgraph[rg, #] & /@ cover, 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightGray"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The next version of IGraph/M (possibly 0.3.100 unless everything comes together for 0.4 ...) will have clique cover as a ready-to-use function,

```
IGCliqueCover[rg]
(* {{1, 3}, {2, 14, 16}, {4, 9}, {5, 13, 20}, {6, 10}, {7, 18}, {8, 11}, {12, 19}, {15, 17}} *)
```

Compared to the above implementation, this function improves performance and ensures that things work in special situations too (e.g. directed graphs).

Also, if you don't need a minimum clique cover (i.e. fewest cliques), then you may want to use the much faster `IGVertexColoring` instead of `IGMinimumVertexColoring`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how

```
g = RandomGraph[{20, 25}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Clique figure]

```
FindClique[g, Infinity, All]

{{3, 4, 17}, {2, 10, 16}, {13, 15}, {13, 14}, {12, 16}, {12, 14}, {11,
   19}, {11, 13}, {7, 9}, {6, 20}, {6, 17}, {6, 10}, {5, 17}, {5, 
  14}, {5, 7}, {3, 8}, {3, 7}, {1, 13}, {1, 9}, {2, 9}, {2, 4}, {18}}
```

In general you cannot partition a graph entirely into cliques, as you seek.

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what the OP is asking, but this seems to find *all* cliques, not just the maximal cliques ([int this sense](http://igraph.org/r/doc/cliques.html)).

Comment: This is not a partition of the vertices. Note that the cliques have non-empty intersections.

Comment: Please clarify what you're seeking.  As stated, in general you cannot partition a graph into cliques as you seem to request.  What would you accept as output for the RandomGraph in the figure, for instance, where there are no independent cliques?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork A trivial partition into cliques that works for *any* graph is a partition into subsets containing single vertices. Of course, that's not what I want, but it illustrates that a partition with the conditions I seek always exists. It's only a matter of choosing the most appropriate.

Comment: David, he's looking for a maximal set of non-overlapping maximal cliques.

Comment: There are 9 configurations that meet his criteria in your graph, one of which is `{{2, 10, 16}, {12, 14}, {11, 19}, {7, 9}, {6, 20}, {5, 17}, {3, 8}, {1, 13}, {18}}`.